# How to comfortably fold socks so that the design of the sock would be outside?

Tags: clothing, storage, organization

I want to fold the socks so that I will be able to see their outer design and organize them nicely in the drawer.

What I'm looking for:

- That they will be "connected" (not only rolled for example).
- That the socks will be in the correct way (not flipped).
- I less care about efficiency in size because it's for the drawer and not traveling.
- I do want it to be comfortable and relatively fast, and not something that would take a lot of time, like [this thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tepzJ7nodxY).

The best method I found so far is this one, from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEI6gWrAVR0):

[image]

It works fine, but only for thin socks. And it's not that fast.

Any more methods I haven't discovered yet?
I don't mind using different methods for different socks types

Thanks!

Comment: When you wash your socks, do you wash them with the inside out or not?

Comment: Nope, they are always with the design outside. I thought about it, that it could be much more easy to fold them if I did wash them that way 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried most of the methods suggested here, and also gave another shot to the method I showed in the question itself (thanks to [user18849](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/24301/user18849) who stated it's actually pretty fast) to check what's more comfortable, fast and organized nicely.

Eventually I found the method I presented to be the best in terms of fastness, organization and "visual availability of the design" in the drawer.

**Final result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you are showing is actually pretty fast way of folding socks once you get used to it (like tying your shoe laces -  remember how difficult and time consuming it used to be). An easier version of this is to roll them instead of folding them (here is my lovely Paint representation of it).
[image]

If you need an even easier way, just tie one sock to the other. 
[image]

It doesn’t look very organised when you have them in the drawer, but it is actually quite convenient – it is quick, you can easily find the pair you want, it works with thick socks too.

Comment: why tie them rather than just the common "roll down" technique?

Comment: @goodguy5 I have no idea what the common "roll down" technique is.

Comment: oh.... Then I guess I should put up an answer.

Comment: I tried the first method, and it's pretty good. But I think you're right about my method pretty fast. I tried both of them a few times and the method I described became much faster after a few tries! Thanks for the answer and illustration!

Comment: +1 for the tying. It does not wear the elastic at the top. I do this for many years.

Answer (score 3):

Stick one sock completely inside the other one.

This way the outer sock is unfolded and any patterns are clearly visible,
and the inner sock is not likely to wiggle out when digging through the sock drawer or pulling from the bottom.

Comment: How does this put the design on the outside?

Comment: If the outer sock shows the design, it wouldn't be hidden by inserting another sock inside it...

Comment: @Chenmunka: Good point, I'll clarify

Comment: It works, but I find it less comfortable doing than other methods. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

I have a technique that may work for you. I'll assume that the "ankle part" of each sock has the design that you want to see, like in the animated GIF in your question.

First, buy a bunch of inexpensive hair clips. You could really use any kind of clip (like clothes pins, binder clips, etc.).

[image]

When you are putting away your clean socks, do each pair separately. Fold one sock in half, then fold the other sock in half, separately.  Put the two socks together with the foot parts touching, so that the design on the ankle is visible from both sides.

[image]

Fasten the pair of socks together with a hair clip.

[image]

That will keep them together, will keep the pattern visible (provided that the clip is clear or a neutral color), and is very simple to do.

Comment: It's actually an interesting idea, but I haven't found it very comfortable and being organized nicely in the drawer, when I have a lot of socks. Thanks for the answer and the drawings!

Answer (score 2):

### Roll one sock into the other.

#### Method 1

Put the two socks so that they overlap "perfectly" (ish). Roll down one of the sock collars (ankles?) so that it overlaps the other sock.

#### Method 2

Bunch up the toe of one sock so that it makes an little pocket. Insert the toe of sock2 into the toe-pocket of sock1.

[This video is the only link online I could find describing either way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3FioLFOUHI)

Comment: In the first method, by rolling down the collar, you mean like he does in [that part of the video?](https://youtu.be/Lga8beldPT0?t=40s) Without giving attention at the moment to the parts before

Comment: @arieljannai I think so. but I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.

Comment: You mean taking to upper part and fold/cover in a way that it will wrap itself and the other sock?

Comment: Yes. Partially. This will cover about 2-3 inches of the side (depending on how far down you roll it), but will leave the majority of the sock viewable.